# First-chance exception (ntdll.dll)

Tags: c++, sfml

Any ideas why I am getting this error?

This is the full error:

> First-chance exception at 0x77202282 (ntdll.dll) in Test.exe 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000004
>
> Unhandle exception at 0x77202282 (ntdll.dll) in Test.exe 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000004

- Debugging breaks at the line `Grid::Grid()`.
- `Root.hpp` contains a private member `static Grid grid;`.
- `Root.cpp` initializes this `Grid Root::Grid;`

I do have `SFML` linked statically, which has caused me a bit of trouble.

This is a small example which exhibits this error:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <Windows.h>

#include "Root.hpp"

Grid Root::grid;

int main (uchar argc, char **argv) {
    Root root;
    Root::Prepare(root);
    return Root::GetStatus();
}
```

The constructor as follows:

```
Grid::Grid() {
    Width = 100;
    Height = 100;
}
```

The call stack:

```
ntdll.dll!772022b2()    Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
Test.exe!sf::priv::MutexImpl::lock(void)    Unknown
Test.exe!sf::Mutex::lock(void)  Unknown
Test.exe!sf::Lock::Lock(class sf::Mutex &)  Unknown
Test.exe!sf::GlResource::GlResource(void)   Unknown
Test.exe!sf::Texture::Texture(void) Unknown
>   Test.exe!Grid::Grid() Line 5    C++
Test.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'Root::grid''() Line 11   C++
msvcr110d.dll!_initterm(void (void) * * pfbegin, void (void) * * pfend) Line 894    C
Test.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 460   C
Test.exe!mainCRTStartup() Line 377  C
kernel32.dll!767533aa() Unknown
ntdll.dll!77219ef2()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!77219ec5()    Unknown
```

Comment: And what are you doing inside the `Grid` constructor? The code you shown is not enough to reliably help you with your problem.

Comment: Is there an actual *problem* somewhere? You see an exception being thrown *and caught*. Do you catch it yourself? If the library throws, and then catches, an exception, what makes you think there is a problem at all?

Comment: Also, can you post the stack-trace? Is the `Grid` constructor being called because of the static variable initialization, or from somewhere else?

Comment: Updated with requested information. Earlier I had an issue with linking statically and globals. In Grid.hpp I have a the line `sf::Texture img;`which I think may be the issue, but I can't be sure.

Comment: You're using a null this pointer to write to member variable that has an offset 4 bytes from the start of its class.

Answer (score 2):

Even without having your full source code, the exception you're getting, and the stack you show, look suspiciously similar to another solved Stack Overflow posting:

"[Unhandled exception at 0x777122D2 (ntdll.dll) in ArticxEngine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326947/unhandled-exception-at-0x777122d2-ntdll-dll-in-articxengine-exe-0xc0000005-a/18330350#18330350)"

Your stack shows that Grid() is derived from SFML's Texture(), which is derived in turn from GlResource(). The problem is that your grid is a static variable which is getting constructed before GlResource()'s internal mutex is.

The solution is the same as the other Stack Overflow posting: make sure your Grid object is non-static and is constructed after your main() begins running.